# How to use Insert query in PHP code

Tags: php, mysql

I do not understand what is going wrong with code. The result is get is "connected successfully success Query failed". I tried few combinations and I get the same result. Please help me in solving this. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root1', '')
    or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

    if ($link) {
        echo 'connected successfully';
    }

    $l = mysql_select_db('vtflix', $link) or die ('Could not select the database');
    if ($l) {
        echo ' success'; 
    }

    /*$varCNAME = 'John';
    $varCONTENT = '4';
    $varVID = '1';*/
    $sql = "INSERT INTO mpaa(C_Name, ContentRating, V_ID) VALUES ('Jon', 4, 3)";  
    mysql_query($sql, $link) or die("Query failed");
    $que = "SELECT * FROM mpaa";
    $query = mysql_query($que, $link);
    if (!$query) {
        echo 'query failed';
    }

    while ($sqlrow = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $row = $sqlrow['C_Name'];
        $nrow = $sqlrow['Content Rating'];
        $mrow = $sqlrow['V_ID'];
        echo "<br>" . $row . " " . $nrow . " " . $mrow . "<br>";
    }
    mysql_close($link);

    ?>
```

Comment: Add code as text not as link to an image

Comment: Share your code with us.

Comment: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*`API. use `mysqli_` or `PDO`.

Comment: use `mysql_error()` to see what is wrong with your query

Comment: Warning mysql_query, mysql_fetch_array,mysql_connect etc.. extensions were deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used

Comment: Remove $link from mysql_query($sql);

Comment: @SoniVimal yes, its here  'mysql_query($sql, $link)'

Comment: @Elby Why should he remove it? It's an optional argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Don't use `mysql_*` library (deprecated from php5 onward + removed from php7) .Use `mysqli_*` OR `PDO`.

2.An example of `mysqli_*`(with your code)is given below:-

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); // check all type of error
ini_set('display_errors',1); // display those errors

$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root1', '','vtflix');

if($link){
    echo 'connected successfully';
    $sql= "INSERT INTO mpaa(C_Name,ContentRating,V_ID) VALUES ('Jon', 4, 3)";
    if(mysqli_query($link,$sql)){

        $query = "SELECT * FROM mpaa";
        $res  =  mysqli_query($link,$query);
        if($res){
            while($sqlrow=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
            {
                $row= $sqlrow['C_Name'];
                $nrow= $sqlrow['Content Rating'];
                $mrow= $sqlrow['V_ID'];
                echo "<br>".$row." ".$nrow." ".$mrow."<br>";
            }
        mysqli_close($link);
        }else{
            echo die('Query error: ' . mysqli_error($link));  
        }
    }else{
        echo die('Query error: ' . mysqli_error($link));  
    }
}else{
  echo die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());  
}
?>
```

Note:- To check php version (either on localhost or on live server) create a file with name `phpInfo.php`, and just write one line code in that file:-

```
<?php  
phpinfo();
?>
```

Now run this file and you will get the current `php` version.

Like this:- https://eval.in/684551

Comment: i tried this.. I'm getting this error
connected successfullyQuery error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Rating,V_ID) VALUES ('Jon', 4, 3)' at line 1

Comment: @KrishChandran  you need to check your column name

Comment: @Anant i don't think the error have to do with column name its syntax error in the query, if was a column it was gonna say unknow column

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile  i didn't see any syntax mistake there

Comment: @Anant thats whats puzzling me currently, I don't see them, But if it was error in column name it was gonna say unknown column

Comment: This code is working fine, i just created the same table and run the insert query is working fine.... @KrishChandran you need to debug your code line by line, start by the insert query first then do the select at later stage

Comment: @KrishChandran Since the error message says `near 'Rating`, I suspect you have a space or some invisible character between `Content` and `Rating`.

Answer (score 0):

Here it seems that you are using deprecated API of mysql_* .

1) Check your PHP version

```
<?php phpinfo();exit;//check version ?>
```

2) avoid the usage of mysql ***use mysqli or PDO***

3) change your db connection string with this :

***new Mysqlidb($hostname, $username, $pwd, $dbname);***

***example*** with you code

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root1', '','vtflix');
if($link){
    echo 'connected successfully';
    $sql= "INSERT INTO mpaa(C_Name,ContentRating,V_ID) VALUES ('Jon', 4, 3)";
    if(mysqli_query($link,$sql)){

        $query = "SELECT * FROM mpaa";
        $res  =  mysqli_query($link,$query);
        if($res){
            while($sqlrow=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
            {
                $row= $sqlrow['C_Name'];
                $nrow= $sqlrow['Content Rating'];
                $mrow= $sqlrow['V_ID'];
                echo "<br>".$row." ".$nrow." ".$mrow."<br>";
            }
            mysqli_close($link);
        }else{
            echo die('Query error: ' . mysqli_error($link));  
        }
    }else{
        echo die('Query error: ' . mysqli_error($link));  
    }
}else{
    echo die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());  
}
?>
```

Comment: how to check php version

Comment: <?php phpinfo(); ?>

Comment: Version is 5.5.38